# Laravel - validate url path

Tags: laravel

How does one validate a url in laravel.

Example I want to allow urls like this:

`https://www.test.com/test`

But not:

`https://www.test.com/test/test`

I only want to allow one path after the base domain.

Thanks

Comment: everything up to the first single slash is the domain. Subtract it from the string.  If the string still contains a forward slash then it is invalid.  Possibly also remove the final trailing slash if there is one, eg www.test.com/test/

Comment: What do yo mean `validate`? If there is no route defined for `/test/test` it won't require validating as it will `404`.

Comment: These routes are not real routes within our application, they are routes users define for accessing their profile on an external site. I need to validate that the inputed route only contains one path

Answer (score 0):

what I actually did for this problem was checking the full URL with url()->current() with the generated URL by me for my categories or my brands page or even my product pages

```
if()urldecode($product->getUrl()) != urldecode(url()->current()){
   dd('hello');
}
```